# Can't grab on to 2nd wheel in Forest Folly (6-5)

Tags: donkey-kong-country-tropical-freeze

In Donkey Kong - Tropical Freeze I am stuck at a part of level 6-5 - Forest Folly. At the second grassy wheel where you are shot out of a barrel at a grassy wheel I am not able to grab on to the wheel. I have varied my timing but no matter what I do I bounce off of it instead of grabbing on. I have absolutely no problems grabbing onto the first grassy wheel. Any tips for getting past this part? I have died about 200 times already and am not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about this?
[image: screenshot of the presumed area in question]
(screenshot appropriated from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKlhVD-1M6s))

If so: There is no trick. There is no timing. As long as you're holding the grab button when you approach the grass, there should be no issue. I suppose maybe you might need to release-and-press-again the grab button after the barrel shoots, but that's the only potential issue I can think of.